# TypewriterJS scoping

Tags: javascript

There seems to be some kind of issue with [Typewriter JS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typewriter-effect) scoping. For instance, in the following code, deleteAll() executes no problem

```js
const typewriter = new Typewriter('#typewriter');

typewriter.start();
typewriter.typeString('Hello, world');
typewriter.deleteAll();
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/typewriter-effect@latest/dist/core.js"></script>
<div id="typewriter"></div>
```

however, when deleteAll() is put inside a function, it does not work.

```js
const typewriter = new Typewriter('#typewriter');

typewriter.start();
typewriter.typeString('Hello, world');

const yes = document.querySelector("#yes");
yes.addEventListener('click', function() {
  typewriter.deleteAll();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/typewriter-effect@latest/dist/core.js"></script>
<div id="typewriter"></div>

<button id="yes">yes</button>
```

All the code is called after DOM content is loaded. Does anyone know what the issue is or how I can fix it?

Comment: I converted your code so it was runnable so it shows the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some weird bug in the typewriter code. You might want to report it that it seems to not restart after it is done.

Seems like it you call stop, with a pause, and start it will allow it to run.

```js
const typewriter = new Typewriter('#typewriter');

typewriter.start();
typewriter.typeString('Hello, world');

const yes = document.querySelector("#yes");
yes.addEventListener('click', function() {
  typewriter.stop().pauseFor(1).start().deleteAll();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/typewriter-effect@latest/dist/core.js"></script>
<div id="typewriter"></div>

<button id="yes">yes</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the `typewriter` variable is not declared in the function scope. This means that the function does not have access to the `typewriter` object, and therefore cannot call the `deleteAll()` method.

To fix this, you need to declare the `typewriter` variable in the function scope. You can do this by adding the following line to the function:

```
let typewriter = document.getElementById("typewriter");
```

This will create a local variable called `typewriter` in the function scope. The function will now be able to access the `typewriter` object and call the `deleteAll()` method.

The following code shows the corrected code:

```
let yes = document.getElementById("yes");
let no = document.getElementById("no");

function onYesClick() {
  let typewriter = document.getElementById("typewriter");
  typewriter.deleteAll();
}

yes.addEventListener("click", onYesClick);
```

Comment: That's complete nonsense. Might as well ask ChatGPT for all the sense this makes.

Comment: @Quentin well before I edited it `typewriter` was not defined... but it clearly is not a DOM element when you looked at the library.

Comment: @epascarello — Clearly not a DOM element when you look at `deleteAll` being a method on it either.